# How to Access Environment Variables In Clojure - Luminus Web Framework

Tags: clojure, environment-variables, luminus

I need help accessing my environment variables. I have `:my-variable "value"` in `dev-config.edn` and I'm trying to access it in another place. I required `[my-app.config :refer [env]]` and trying the following:

```
(defn my-function []
  (def variable (-> env :my-variable))
  (println (str "my environment variable: " variable)))
```

I tried this and several other things... What's the right to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure can read environment variables via Java, so try this:

```
(System/getenv "my-variable")
```

Environment variables are strings, as far as Java is concerned.  Whatever reads "dev-config.edn" converts your `:my-variable` keyword to a string.  Perhaps this is it:  https://github.com/yogthos/config .  It mentions some details of the conversion, including "names lowercased, then `_` and `.` characters converted to dashes".